# Can Google Prediction API be used to develop Predictive Chat Bot?

Tags: chatbot, livechat, google-prediction

I was just fiddling around different machine learning platforms and was planing to use Google predictive API for creating predictive chat bot.

The issue that I am facing now is each request to the API requires OAuth authentication. The fact that I will not be able to authenticate requests for processing the text entered by a client is the real concern. How will I probably respond to a text entered in the chat by a guest user in real time? Is it possible or is Google predictive API not made for this use case?

I am following [Prediction API Quick Start Guide by Google](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/quickstart) and using POST MAN for making API calls.
If possible, please guide me using references or code snippet.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

You can create service accounts in place of OAuth authentication tokens. You can create these through the Google Cloud Console. It will then give you the ability to create a server to server (Google) auth that you can use to interact with the API.

Comment: document reads "A service account is a special account that can be used by services and applications running on your Google Compute Engine instance to interact with other Google Cloud Platform APIs". So technically i would be able to use this if and only if my site resides in a google cloud instance, if i am not getting it wrong ?

Comment: You can use any infrastructure you want. The service account's credentials allow you to access the service.