# How to integrate a Google Natural Language API with Chatfuel?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, chatfuel

My coding skills and familiarity with Google Cloud solutions are limited and I'm trying to consume a Machine Learning model from a chatbot build using the platform Chatfuel.

I've trained a Natural Language Machine learning model using Google NL and I wanted to use this code snippet provided in my model page:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/123456/locations/us-central1/models/ABC123:predict \
  -d @request.json
```

I've then tried to pass this information in Chatbot like this:

[image]

The problem is it looks like I need to pass a token (API key seems not possible for this API) and I don't see how from the Chatfuel interface I could obtain a token for each request and pass it in my post request.

**Edit: I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906015/can-google-prediction-api-be-used-to-develop-predictive-chat-bot?rq=1) and created a service account but I don't see how to pass the credentials to Chatfuel.**

**How can I pass Google API service account credential to Chatfuel?**

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with Chatfuel, but it should have some backend server where you could add the credentials  from your service account as mentinoned in [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application). However, actually, as per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) you should be able to create API key for the service aforementioned (Natural Language). Could you take a look at let me know if that might work for you?

Comment: try add key=<YOUR KEY HERE> after .../ABC123:predict? in your POST request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a [service account with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

It should give you a JSON with an API key, which is used to generate a new token every hour or so. Using the Google API for whatever server side language you are using (or just using the native http requests), you use the service key (which in general is loaded into your server as a .json file) to fetch a new token every hour; OR you can use Google Apps Script, if they have Chatfuel available (which I'm not sure if they do) and get the token there, and send it to your own app every 30 minutes or so via a trigger.

But the main thing is: using your service API key, you make an HTTP request to a certain api URL (available on [with instructions from another page from that link above](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials)) every hour or so to generate a new token.

From the docs, that URL appears to be:

```
POST https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/SA-4@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken
```

just replace, "`

> `SA-4@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

`"

with your own service account name
That's about it, its how it works for all Google Cloud APIs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does that mean I can't simply use an API key but instead I'll still have to request a token every hour?

Comment: @psql that's how a service account works, most people set up on their server, if, using nodeJS for example, something like `setInterval(function(){getNewToken()}, 1000 * 60 * 50 /*leave 10 extra minutes or something*/)` but a possible workaround is to have one server that gets the token within every hour, and simply make an API request to that server, from some other server (or something) for the current API key.